Sanctum API: 419 CSRF token mismatch with laradock
I created a project in Laravel 11 with Laradock in multi-project and thus defined the host in the hosts file:
127.0.0.6 laravel.api.test

config/cors.php
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'auth/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
];

bootstrap/app.php:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

routes/web:
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/login', LoginController::class);
});

.env:
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=.api.test

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=laravel.api.test

then I call this route in POST with postman :
http://laravel.api.test/auth/login

as parameters in the header step:
Accept:application/json
X-CSRF-TOKEN:{{xsrf-token}}

and in the Pre-request-script section:
pm.sendRequest({
    url: "http://laravel.api.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie",
    method: "GET"
}, function (err, res, { cookies }) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('xsrf-token', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
        pm.globals.set('xsrf-token', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'))
    }
})

I get the following error 419:
{
    "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/laravel_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 633,
    "trace": [

LOG POSTMAN
GET http://laravel.api.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie
204
42 ms
xsrf-token
eyJpdiI6IlZDSis1d2kyR0lXWWdWc2VEeEV3MGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ3htNlBaYXlwL2d0dlBITXpGZVp3ejN4V1NGYm5iK21EWGI1dFZObEZlNmhRZ1UrWXVLUlk0SmhPckZ4YUdJUjZuK3hBcVl4YkpDZnNKMisyRmQyYkhITlBVblhjdWxpdU92aFc4NU5MOTVYSWIzTE1wU3dOVzFCTXJMMGt3UDEiLCJtYWMiOiI0NWNiOTY4MWRhZjdjYmNhNjQyMjY5MGQzMGQ5MzYxZWFjNjljODIzYmQ0NDUwNzUwNjQ1MmEwNzI0NGI3ZDcyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=

POST http://laravel.api.test/auth/login
419
75 ms
Network
Request Headers
Accept: application/json
X-CSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IlZDSis1d2kyR0lXWWdWc2VEeEV3MGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ3htNlBaYXlwL2d0dlBITXpGZVp3ejN4V1NGYm5iK21EWGI1dFZObEZlNmhRZ1UrWXVLUlk0SmhPckZ4YUdJUjZuK3hBcVl4YkpDZnNKMisyRmQyYkhITlBVblhjdWxpdU92aFc4NU5MOTVYSWIzTE1wU3dOVzFCTXJMMGt3UDEiLCJtYWMiOiI0NWNiOTY4MWRhZjdjYmNhNjQyMjY5MGQzMGQ5MzYxZWFjNjljODIzYmQ0NDUwNzUwNjQ1MmEwNzI0NGI3ZDcyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=
Content-Type: text/plain
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.37.0
Postman-Token: 7ff581ea-e9b2-4b69-8423-a7c9ff349e83
Host: laravel.api.test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 60
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZDSis1d2kyR0lXWWdWc2VEeEV3MGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ3htNlBaYXlwL2d0dlBITXpGZVp3ejN4V1NGYm5iK21EWGI1dFZObEZlNmhRZ1UrWXVLUlk0SmhPckZ4YUdJUjZuK3hBcVl4YkpDZnNKMisyRmQyYkhITlBVblhjdWxpdU92aFc4NU5MOTVYSWIzTE1wU3dOVzFCTXJMMGt3UDEiLCJtYWMiOiI0NWNiOTY4MWRhZjdjYmNhNjQyMjY5MGQzMGQ5MzYxZWFjNjljODIzYmQ0NDUwNzUwNjQ1MmEwNzI0NGI3ZDcyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImRyUGh2ZklLUFhYbCtwTnpqSWZ0SHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ1BJbGloZGhPYmlKTlpTSHIxZjNTQVhEQkpER210NWlhdlpwVUN3OFJkTkJ5UmdKWVpZOVNybE9uV2NaTWtiNGZCZnEzanpRNi81T08zOE43ME9pTnhhMmJScEhDc1hXeGc0emJnQUl2VjgvZXd3a0NneU9xZm9nYTljblllb0YiLCJtYWMiOiIwMDVmYzM0ODcwZmZlMTU3OWJhYTJjNjhlOTAxNzE4OTFlMDI4OGQ1Y2ZhNWUxZWJhNTBjY2E2Y2RlOWI2ODEzIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; tC8zpXwRJnmAZKHQkeY1sldxapFyUQ545wEeOmLq=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
Request Body
Response Headers
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.3.4
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2024 10:36:55 GMT
Vary: Origin
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImVodzRoUHFZN25qWTZTU0h3QmRPanc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieThJUnE5L1lkRFdBK3NQSTlubzJOUFVSVjA5V2RvTkVtSnBXL25Md3ZWWEJ4Q2xRT3RuTXhqMGhaamdjK1JqL3N5SGV5MDdkMzZURW85SUkxbW1GUS9mdTdoRGllMTJVeGN6cVk3bTBiSlA4dUpYQUtZeDBFWXg4cmtLeEdKL3EiLCJtYWMiOiI2MTRmYTdhMTQ3MmFmNzhkODczYzZkNjhiMGE2NGE5YjBhYWE2NDkzZGMyZTliZDk1OTI0MDVkZWE1YTUxYTgzIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 04 Apr 2024 12:36:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.api.test; httponly; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: tC8zpXwRJnmAZKHQkeY1sldxapFyUQ545wEeOmLq=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; expires=Thu, 04 Apr 2024 12:36:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.api.test; httponly; samesite=lax


SESSION_DOMAIN=.api.test <<== I would change that into laravel.api.test, let's sew if that helps

I already tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. When it passes through the VerifyCsrfToken middleware it fails in the tokensMatch method hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token) from false this is the xsrf-token that I pass to it

eyJpdiI6IjZTU0dpOTMrajArZDR3TXVvUSswaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieWNBeGkyM2tOTUw1V1NrR3ZkbTll NFQ2amxSTThkTE0xM2ozdmgyZkYybnB4dzVoYUhFZVU3QTloK2x2TkVCMHRORXMzSTNMMSs3d0QvNnNRallvbk9LYVoxejNPVFVmVXR6R2hwdjM5Um9LdkxhK3pRTklXS2poaUY2WDh5bXkiLCJtYWMiOi IzNmI0NTZmY2I3NzI2Y2IwNmRhMWVhNmFjMjcwMTUzODg1NDZlNDZiM2YzMzkzNDdkYzdlNjFlNWJmNzhhYWQ0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0

I solved it by changing the pre request script:
  pm.sendRequest({
    url: "http://laravel.api.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie",
    method: "GET"
}, function (err, res, { cookies }) {
    if (!err) {
        const xsrfToken = cookies.has('XSRF-TOKEN') ? cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN') : null;
        if (xsrfToken) {
            // Add X-XSRF-TOKEN to the header of the subsequent request
            console.log('xsrfToken', xsrfToken);
            pm.request.headers.add({ key: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', value: xsrfToken });
        } else {
            console.error('XSRF-TOKEN not found in cookies');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Error fetching CSRF token:', err);
    }
});

the problem was the token encoding problem with postman and insomnia so I managed to solve it.

Make sure that the CSRF token is being updated correctly and included in the POST request. If the issue persists, you may need to further check your Laravel environment configuration to ensure that CSRF token management is properly set up.
